# Como hacer un insert por cada checkbox seleccionado?

Tags: c#, sql

Ingreso usuario y en la parte permisos selecciono los checkbox según los permisos que tendrá dentro del sistema, en mi tabla se hace un registro por cada permiso que se le quiera asignar, por algún motivo no me guarda. Cual podrá ser el problema?
ESTE ES EL HTML

```
<h3>Asignación De Permisos</h3>
                <div style="text-align:left; color:white;">
                    <ul style="display:inline;">
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input name="AsignarRecursos[]" value="1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                <span>Crear Comisión</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input name="AsignarRecursos[]" value="2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                <span>Autorizar comisión</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                            <label class="anim">
                                <input name="AsignarRecursos[]`introducir el código aquí`" value="3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                <span>Asignar recursos</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
</div>

ESTA ES MI LOGICA

 int[] AsignarRecursos = new int[];
            foreach (int AsignarRecursos2 in AsignarRecursos) {
                cn2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RolUsuario (DPIUsuario,IDdetalleRol,estado) VALUES ('" + acc.Name + "','" + AsignarRecursos2 + "','1') ", cn2);
               
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: algun error que te salga? usa try catch para saber cual es el error.

Comment: Ese código está abierto a inyección de SQL. Investiga más acerca de como evitarlo al parametrizar tus sentencias de SQL. Otro punto es que deberías de insertar todos los datos en una sola llamada para hacer más eficiente el uso de recursos.

Comment: En ese foreach estás abriendo una nueva conexión a la base de datos por cada elemento en la lista. Si tienes doscientos mil elementos, vas a abrir doscientas mil conexiones? Y veo que no estás cerrando ninguna....

Comment: No guarda porque estas inicializando el array int[] AsignarRecursos = new int[]; y luego le haces un foreach a AsignarRecursos que esta vacio.